# how to get json keys and values of a column stacked in different columns respectively Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to get keys and values of column which has some rows as json and others as string/None. I want to get each json key and it's value stacked into new different columns respectively.
Json can be nested type and I `don't know the schema of json rows beforehand (like how many keys are/ how nested it is)`.

`Data set has 100s millions of rows`.

Sample data:

```
+-----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|col1 |col2 | col3     |     col4                                              | 
+-----+-----+----------+--------------------------------------------------------
|1    |A    | hello1   |   time1                                               |    
|2    |B    | hello2   |    None
|3    |C    | hello3   |  {'world1': 'how are you?','world2':{'help me!':'please'}}                
|4    |D    | hello4   |  {'world3':'ola!'}                                    |                 
+-----+-----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Expected dataframe:

```
+--------+-------------------+-------------------------------+
|col1 |col2 | col3     | new_col_keys   |   new_col_values   |
+--------+-------------------+----------+--------------------+
|1    |A    | hello1   |   time1                Null         |                        
|2    |B    | hello2   |   Null                 Null         |
|3    |C    | hello3   |  world1                how are you? |
|3    |C    | hello3   |  world2        {'help me!':'please'}|                  
|4    |D    | hello4   |  world3                ola!         |
+-----+-----+----------+-------------------------------------+
```

Here I am adding new columns for keys and values differently and deleting the original one.

> NOTE: All columns in Sample data are of StringType

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try the following :

1. Using the type and function imports from `pyspark.sql`
2. Filter out non-json type records using pattern matching (eg. `LIKE`) not (`~`) like as json dictionary/map type values have the pattern `{key:value}` and store in a dataframe `df_simple`
3. Filter out json type dictionary records using pattern matching using `LIKE` and store results in a dataframe `df_map`.
4. Cast records to [`MapType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.types.MapType.html) with string keys and string values using [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html)
5. Use `select` to retrieve desired columns and [`explode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.explode.html) to get each key/value pair from the transformed `MapType` column `col4`, into a new row
6. Rename exploded columns names (`key`->`new_col_keys` and `value`->`new_col_values`) using [`withColumnRenamed`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumnRenamed.html)
7. Use a union to combine `df_simple` and `df_map` into final data set `output_df` (*While using the `select` in the union is optional, it ensures that the rigth columns are used even if the dataframe changes in the future*)

***NB.** Sections related to steps in code are included as comments*

```py
# Step 1
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T
```

```py
df_simple = df.where(~ F.col("col4").like("{%}")) #Step 2
df_simple.show() # only for debugging purposes
```

```
+----+----+------+-----+
|col1|col2|  col3| col4|
+----+----+------+-----+
|   1|   A|hello1|time1|
|   2|   B|hello2| null|
+----+----+------+-----+
```

```py
df_maps = (
    # Step 3
    df.where(F.col("col4").like("{%}")) 
    # Step 4
      .withColumn("col4",F.from_json( 
          F.col("col4"),
          T.MapType(T.StringType(),T.StringType())
      ))
      # Step 5
      .select(
          F.col("col1"),
          F.col("col2"),
          F.col("col3"),
          F.explode("col4")
      )
      # Step 6
      .withColumnRenamed("key","new_col_keys")
      .withColumnRenamed("value","new_col_values")
)
df_maps.show(truncate=False) # only for debugging purposes
```

```
+----+----+------+------------+---------------------+
|col1|col2|col3  |new_col_keys|new_col_values       |
+----+----+------+------------+---------------------+
|3   |C   |hello3|world1      |how are you?         |
|3   |C   |hello3|world2      |{"help me!":"please"}|
|4   |D   |hello4|world3      |ola!                 |
+----+----+------+------------+---------------------+
```

```py
# Step 7
output_df = (
    df_simple.selectExpr("col1","col2","col3","col4 as new_col_keys","NULL as new_col_values")
             .union(
                 df_maps.select("col1","col2","col3","new_col_keys","new_col_values")
             )
)
output_df.printSchema() # only for debugging
output_df.show(truncate=False)  # only for debugging
```

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- new_col_keys: string (nullable = true)
 |-- new_col_values: string (nullable = true)

+----+----+------+------------+---------------------+
|col1|col2|col3  |new_col_keys|new_col_values       |
+----+----+------+------------+---------------------+
|1   |A   |hello1|time1       |null                 |
|2   |B   |hello2|null        |null                 |
|3   |C   |hello3|world1      |how are you?         |
|3   |C   |hello3|world2      |{"help me!":"please"}|
|4   |D   |hello4|world3      |ola!                 |
+----+----+------+------------+---------------------+
```

**NB.** *If you would like to repeat this for nested columns. You could repeat the operations from Steps 3 - 7. However, this time instead of using `col4`, you would use `new_col_keys` since `col4` would no longer exist in the transformed dataset.*

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: it worked thanks but can you please explain what is going on each step as commenting out and what if i have to unnest `new_col_values` futher into new columns?

Comment: @martian_rover I've updated the answer. Let me know if this is clearer.